# mod_security configuration issue: Error parsing actions: Unknown action: ver

Tags: apache-2.2, security, ddos, mod-security

I am trying to install / configure mod-sec using [this tutorial](http://notepad2.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/ubuntu-1204-precise-lts-install.html), which uses the OWASP [ModSecurity Core Rule Set](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_ModSecurity_Core_Rule_Set_Project). However when I go to restart apache, I get the following error:

```
Syntax error on line 53 of /etc/modsecurity/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_20_protocol_violations.conf:
Error parsing actions: Unknown action: ver
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
...fail!
```

This is the block of code it is having trouble with: (specifically `ver:'OWASP_CRS/2.2.9',\`)

```
SecRule REQUEST_LINE "!^(?i:(?:[a-z]{3,10}\s+(?:\w{3,7}?://[\w\-\./]*(?::\d+)?)?/[^?#]*(?:\?[^#\s]*)?(?:#[\S]*)?|connect (?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\.?(?::\d+)?|options \*)\s+[\w\./]+|get /[^?#]*(?:\?[^#\s]*)?(?:#[\S]*)?)$"\
  "msg:'Invalid HTTP Request Line',\
  severity:'4',\
  id:'960911',\
  ver:'OWASP_CRS/2.2.9',\
  rev:'2',\
  maturity:'9',\
  accuracy:'9',\
  logdata:'%{request_line}',\
  phase:1,\
  block,\
  t:none,\
  tag:'OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/INVALID_REQ',\
  tag:'CAPEC-272',\
  setvar:'tx.msg=%{rule.msg}',\
  setvar:tx.anomaly_score=+%{tx.notice_anomaly_score},\
  setvar:'tx.%{rule.id}-OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/INVALID_REQ-%{matched_var_name}=%{matched_var}'"
```

I have installed `modsec Version: 2.6.3-1ubuntu0.2` so I beleve it should work with the `OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set`

Any ideas on how to get it working? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the version of mod_security that you have installed ?

Comment: 2.6.3-1ubuntu0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling yout error message I found [this](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=mod-security-users&max_rows=50&style=nested&viewmonth=201209)

> ...
>
> Now apache fails to start:
>   Sep 30 15:30:14 mydomain httpd[2377]: Syntax error on line 52 of /etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_20_protocol_violations.conf:
>   Sep 30 15:30:14 mydomain httpd[2377]: Error parsing actions: Unknown action: ver

and the response is

> This is my bad...  CRS v2.2.6 uses some new actions from ModSecurity v2.7.0 -
>
> - ver
> - maturity
> - accuracy

It looks like the CRS that you are using is too new for the version of mod_security that you have installed. You will need to update to a later version of mod_security or find an older version of the CRS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply....Thats really strange because im using CRS v2.2.5 which should be compatible with my version of mod_sec. Do you know how I can upgrade my version of mod_sec on ubuntu 21.04? using the apt-get install libapache2-mod-security command doesn't get the latest version.

Comment: @BobFlemming: The rule you quote says `OWASP_CRS/2.2.9` and I don't use Ubuntu

Comment: ah I see. I had some old files still in the /modsecurity/base_rules/ from a previous installation attempt which are coded for version 2.0.7. After deleting these files I have managed to restart apache only to see 404 forbidden errors. Gotta love false positives!

Comment: @BobFlemming: Ah yes and now the world of pain begins ...

Answer (score 3):

The OWASP rule set has been upgraded to require modsecurity >= 2.7.

There is a downgrade script in the *[util/rule-management](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/tree/master/util/rule-management)* folder that can automatically downgrade rulesets to be 2.6 compatible.

To downgrade your activated rules just run this comand in the rule directory (requires perl):

```
perl <PATH_TO_OWASP_RULESET_TGZ>/SpiderLabs-owasp-modsecurity-crs-ebe8790/util/rule-management/remove-2.7-actions.pl -t 2.6 -f .
```

Comment: could you explain the `-t 2.6 -f .` part?

Comment: -t: target version, -f: file or directory to convert. you can take a look here: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/blob/master/util/rule-management/remove-2.7-actions.pl